# How to configure xdemorse?

Tags: sound, soundcard

`xdemorse` is a morse code decoding software. But I don't know how to configure it. This is what the main window looks like:

[image]

But after I press the receive button I get this error message.
[image] Does anyone know how to configure this software? I printed the user manual, but it leaves some questions unanswered. I found the name of the configuration file, too. For anyone who is interested it is `/usr/share/doc/xdemorse`. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to install osspd as it was never programmed for pulseaudio, and also copy over the configuration file to your users home directory

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdemorse/+bug/661963

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: @williamts99 Thank you. That worked, but now I have a different error message.